# Define a value that can be access from anywhere, with out deceleration

Tags: php

I need to define a variable with file path in PHP file(or any file), I need to access that variable without including any files,

If I use session variable means, I cannot access it when session cleared/Empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you define any variable with file path then you need to include the file in order to access it.

Comment: In which framework?

Comment: want to work in core PHP

Comment: Use database storage

Comment: `I cannot access it when session cleared/Empty` its okay this should removed when use logged out. User can't clear session only you/server-side accessed can clear session.

Comment: @Niklesh Raut, For that also I need to include DB file in all pages or connect DB in all pages. That affects while changing DB name

Comment: @Madhan: Why you don't want to include file. otherwise copy paste code in all file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create .htaccess file in the root directory and added this line to the .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv SPECIAL_PATH /foo/bin
```

Then you can use globally

```
<?php $specialPath = getenv('SPECIAL_PATH'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your variables in $GLOBALS array like

```
$GLOBALS['myvariable'] = 'myvalue';
```

Check the reference for more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Or you can use `define();`:

```
define("MYPATH", "localhost");
```

https://www.php.net/define